# Templated member function pointer as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am looking to accept a templated member function as a template parameter.

For example, given this class:

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void Foo(Args...) {}

    void Bar() {}
};
```

I would like to be able to call:

```
Invoke<&A::Foo>(5, true);
```

And have this be similar to calling:

```
A a;
a.Foo(5, true);
```

I know how to do this for `Bar()`:

```
template<void (A::*F)()>
void Invoke()
{
    A a;
    (a.*F)();
}

int main()
{
    Invoke<&A::Bar>();
}
```

Is it possible to extend this to a templated member function pointer?  Or similarly, to write a forwarding function like this that can handle a function with any parameter types.  This doesn't work, but something similar to:

```
template<typename... Args, void (A::*F)(Args...)>
void Invoke(Args... args)
{
    A a;
    (a.*F)(args...);
}
```

I can see why this might not be possible, but if that's true could you point to the standard for why?  I am also trying to learn more about the specifics of the standard.

Comment: Try `Invoke<&A::Foo<int, bool>>(5, true)`. If that works, write a type-deducing wrapper *function* template.

Comment: @KerrekSB But I don't know how to specify in the function types that Invoke should accept a function with this signature (without hardcoding it), because you seem to have to specify the parameters when you specify the member function pointer type.

Comment: Well, you can make `Invoke` a more powerful template...

Comment: @KerrekSB And therein lies the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to extend this to a templated member function pointer?

No. Although if you just need a particular instantiation of `Foo` you could use `Invoke<&A::Foo<int, bool>>`.

> Or similarly, to write a forwarding function like this that can handle a function with any parameter types.

To be able to work with different signatures, you would have to modify `Invoke` to operate on any kind of *callable* object. Then, you would have to define a *callable* object that calls your actual function:

```
struct callable_foo
{
    explicit callable_foo( A& obj ) : _obj( obj ){}

    template< typename ...Args >
    void operator ()( Args&&... args )
    {
         _obj.Foo( std::forward< Args >( args )... );
    }

    A& _obj;
}
```

Comment: You mean `std::forward<Args>(args)...` instead of `std::forward<Args...>(args)` ?

Comment: @Nawaz: Right, thank you. Still catching up with _perfect forwarding_